# Question about \spacechar in cwebmac.tex

Tags: plain-tex

In [cwebmac.tex](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/web/cweb/cwebmac.tex) the following construct is used:

```
{\def\\{\global\let\spacechar= }\\ }
```

In cwebmac.tex `\spacechar` is used only once, in the following code:

```
...
\else\ifx\nxt\spacechar \addF\space
...
```

Why is `\spacechar` defined in such a curious manner?

Comment: An equivalent definition with the same number of tokens (but it requires `\space` to be defined) is `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\let\noexpand\spacecharB=\space\space}\x`

Comment: @egreg as usual goes for the verbose long form, a more compact definition is `\lowercase{\let\spacecharC= } %` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was described by @David, we need to say `\let\spacetoken=space space` in order to set space-token to the control sequence `\spacetoken`. There are more elegant ways to do this:

```
\def\tmp/{\let\spacetoken= }\tmp/ %
or
\edef\tmp{\let\noexpand\spacetoken= \space}\tmp
or
\lowercase{\let\spacetoken= }
```

IMHO, most elegant way is never to use `\spacetoken`. The `\ifx` test can be done by

```
\expandafter\ifx\space\nxt ...
```

so, you need not any `\spacetoken`.

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX has a very similar definition

```
\def\:{\let\@sptoken= } \:  % this makes \@sptoken a space token
```

If you want `\spacechar` to be an implicit `x` you could use

```
\let\spacechar x
```

or

```
\let\spacechar=x
```

or

```
\let\spacechar = x
```

as space characters are absorbed after the `\spacechar` csname and one optional space is ignored after `=` in the `\let` syntax.

So to get a space instead of `x` you need

```
\let\spacechar =[space][space]
```

where `[space]` is a space token. the first one is discarded as an optional space and the second one is taken as the value.

Typing two space tokens is tricky as if you type two space characters they only make one token but you can add them indirectly, one space in the definition of `\\` and one space following the `\\` token.

```
 \def\\{\global\let\spacechar= }\\ }
                              ^   ^
```